# Dictionary comprehension method not working in Python 2.65

Tags: python-3.6, python-2.6, dictionary-comprehension

I wrote a script in a Python 3.6 environment and now need to translate it back to Python 2.65. There is one line of code that it particularly disapproves of. I used dictionary comprehension to make a variable. 
Note: `NFHL_sx_firmpan` and `Prelim_sx_firmpan` are dictionaries that I am comparing to find the differences that are 'not shared' between them.-

```
 unshared = {k: NFHL_sx_firmpan[k] for k in NFHL_sx_firmpan if k not in Prelim_sx_firmpan}
```

It throws a synatax error on the 'for', so I tried to use an old `for` loop with a conditional:

```
 unshared = dict()
 for k in NFHL_sx_firmpan:
     if k not in Prelim_sx_firmpan:
        unshared = k: NFHL_sx_firmpan[k]
```

It now throws a syntax error on the `':'` after `'k'`. How can I translate this so that it works in 2.65? (Note2: it works fine asis in 3.6)

Comment: `unshared = k: NFHL_sx_firmpan[k]` ->         `unshared[k] = NFHL_sx_firmpan[k]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there anything preventing you from doing the following?  This syntax should work in both versions.

```
unshared = {}
for k in NFHL_sx_firmpan:
    if k not in Prelim_sx_firmpan:
        unshared[k] = NFHL_sx_firmpan[k]
```

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. Not sure why I didn't see that earlier. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The code below should be compatible with version less than Python 2.7

```
unshared = dict((k, NFHL_sx_firmpan[k]) for k in NFHL_sx_firmpan if k not in Prelim_sx_firmpan)
```